# Upgrading Spring Boot from 1.3.2. to 1.4.0 unsatisfied dependencies error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to upgrade my spring boot from 1.3.2 to 1.4.0, I followed the `spring-boot-1.4-release-notes` but I am getting an error that says unsatisfied dependency.

```
 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ADUserRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:435)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:220)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:266)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:252)
        at org.springframework.ldap.repository.support.LdapRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LdapRepositoryFactoryBean.java:47)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        ... 53 common frames omitted
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your "ADUserRepo" class. Probably interfaces changed between versions. You are getting "AbstractMethodError" exception. Could you post source code for "ADUserRepo"?

Comment: I found many similar questions with an `AbstractMethodError`. Most of the accepted answers say that it's a problem of dependencies, where there is several version of the same class. I suggest you to do some more researches or add more information to your question, like your pom.xml

Comment: You are using incompatible versions. You are upgrading Spring Boot but some of your other dependencies are explicitly defined instead of managed by Spring Boot. Leading to these kind of issues.

Comment: My ADUserRepo extends Ldap   and I believe the dependency issue is to do with the Ldap version                                                                                                                      `@Component
public interface ADUserRepo extends LdapRepository<ADUser> {

 //ADUser findByFullName(String uid);
 
 List<ADUser> findByLastNameContains(String lastName);
 List<ADUser> findBySAMAccountName(String samAccountName);
 List<ADUser> findByFullName(String cnName);
 
}`

Comment: from my pom.xml below is the Ldap dependency      `<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE </version>
        </dependency>`